# (Android)How to clear keyboard memory in certain situation(Acer Keyboard)

Tags: android, keyboard

In the first place, Thank everyone for coming in and sorry for my poor English, So I describe this situation directly,

I develop with SONY, When I clicked the clear button in EditText, it's working normally!, even I use others phone, like HTC, Oppo,mi..   All's well!

After that I tried to install it in Acer, the clear button still working,

BUT!!!!!

After I clicked the clear button, Next use keyboard again, the data of my first input still here.

[The data of my first input.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIEVr.png)

So, "MyFirstData" will still appear when I input again like

[Second-time input situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6cPw.png)

I was really confused because I have no idea how to fix it.

So what can I do, clear keyboard data?   How?

many thanks!!!!

Code here:
binding.searchView is my editext

```
binding.searchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcherAdapter());
    binding.searchView.setOnEditorActionListener(getSearchEditListener());
    channelDialogHelper = new ChannelDialogHelper(this);
}

private TextView.OnEditorActionListener getSearchEditListener() {
    return new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                messageResultAdapter.clearAdapter();
                shareFileResultAdapter.clearAdapter();
                keyword = MessageFactory.getInstance().parseSourceData(v.getText().toString());
                if (StringUtil.isEmpty(keyword)) {
                    return false;
                }

                hasMessageResult = false;
                hasFileResult = false;

                if (binding.searchMessageButton.isSelected()) {
                    searchMessageListener(binding.searchMessageButton);

                } else if (binding.searchFileButton.isSelected()) {
                    searchFileListener(binding.searchFileButton);
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

TextWatcherAdapter:

```
public class TextWatcherAdapter implements TextWatcher {
public TextWatcherAdapter() {
}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence var1, int var2, int var3, int var4) {
}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence var1, int var2, int var3, int var4) {
}

public void afterTextChanged(Editable var1) {
}
```

}

Comment: Are you kidding me? Where is your code?

Comment: i'm editing now, give me a second

Comment: I met the same problem..

Comment: ohh ,did u solve it?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to remove the exact word(s) using ContentResolver.delete(). Example:

```
private int deleteWord(String word) {
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(word)) {
    return -1;
}
return getContentResolver().delete(UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI,
        UserDictionary.Words.WORD + "=?", new String[] { word });
}
```

And of course, need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY" />
```

defined in the manifest.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but next time input,it still here, that's like keyboard memory or something like that

Comment: try this one:which disable suggestions on the Soft Keyboard by adding the following line in the xml -

android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"

Comment: it's not working, i only want to second time without suggestions